# What is the difference between a defining equation and a word definition?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, definition

For example, can we define kinetic energy as the product of 1/2mu^2 and also as the energy that an object has due to motion ? are these definitions equivalent ?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410874/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic This post is closed.